# as_html in HTML::TagParser

Tags: html, perl

I'm working in perl

I would like to ask if there is something like

```
$value->as_html()
```

from HTML::TreeBuilder in HTML::TagParser;

I extracted tag which I needed in HTML::TagParser, but now the only option is:

```
$value->innerText();
```

which give me only text without HTML tags

Or maybe can I somehow connect result from HTML::TagParser with HTML::TreeBuilder, and take my HTML tags like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HTML::TagParser` does not only read the element content. It also keeps the element name and the attribute key/value pairs for each selected element. Therefore you can easily reproduce the complete HTML code of the element.

Actually, the `HTML::TagParser` [CPAN page](http://search.cpan.org/~kawasaki/HTML-TagParser-0.20/lib/HTML/TagParser.pm) contains an example for this: The following code extracts all `<a>`nchor tags from a web page and reproduces them into an HTML fragment listing precisely these tags.

```
my $url  = 'http://www.kawa.net/xp/index-e.html';
my $html = HTML::TagParser->new( $url );
my @list = $html->getElementsByTagName( "a" );
foreach my $elem ( @list ) {
    my $tagname = $elem->tagName;
    my $attr = $elem->attributes;
    my $text = $elem->innerText;
    print "<$tagname";
    foreach my $key ( sort keys %$attr ) {
        print " $key=\"$attr->{$key}\"";
    }
    if ( $text eq "" ) {
        print " />\n";
    } else {
        print ">$text</$tagname>\n";
    }
}
```

This works pretty well for simple element scanning. For more complex tasks (e.g. mixed inner HTML content) I would prefer to work with `HTML::Parser`.

Comment: Thank You. I will try this. I wouldn't not like to change, when my code is almost complete. I have only problem with this thing but it's not the most important thing in this code.

I have question. Since HTML::TagParser has something like
    
$something = $value->$subTree
"This method returns a new object of class HTML::Parser,
with all the elements that are in the DOM hierarchy under $elem."

Then can't I work with "$something" like with HTML::Parser object? If yes would HTML::parser printing html work in my example?